# Xamarin Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: W. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc and ms sql. It gives 2 errors. I didnt understand why.

```
private string Url = @"http://192.168.x.x/HbbTestLast/";
    private async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        return client;            
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<oyunlar>> GetAll()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        HttpClient client = await GetClient();
        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(Url + "/oyunlar/oyunlariGetir");
        var mobileResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <oyunlar>(result, jsSettings);
        //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<oyunlar>>(client.ToString(), jsSettings);
        var deneme = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<oyunlar>>(mobileResult.ToString());
        return deneme;

    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<salonlar>> PostSalon()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        HttpClient client = await GetClient();
        var result = await client.PostAsync(Url,new StringContent(@"salonlars/"));
        var mobileResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<salonlar>(result.ToString(), jsSettings);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<salonlar>>(mobileResult.ToString(), jsSettings);

    }
}
```

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VS7A.png) Newtonsoft.Json.SerializableException: Error converting value...

[Second Error][2] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReaderException: Unexpected character...

how can i solve it?

**Update**

```
private async void LoadData()
    {
       try
        {
            var collection = await manager.GetAll();
            foreach (oyunlar item in collection)
                model.Add(item);
            //lstOyunlar.BindingContext = collection;
        }
       catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Hata :", ex.ToString(), "Ok", "Cancel");
        }
    }
```

`GetAll()` sends null with `GetAll()` and PostSalon()

***Update***
Serializable for GetAll()

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult OyunlariGetir(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var oyunListe = db.oyunlars.Include(o => o.oyun_turu).Include(o => o.salonlar);
        JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        var converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oyunListe, null, jsSettings);
        return Json(converted, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And PostSalon()

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult  SalonlariGetir()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        var salonListe = db.salonlars;
        var converted =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salonListe, null, jsSettings);            
        return Json(converted, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      //  return converted;
    }
```

***Update***

```
public virtual DbSet<salonlar> salonlars { get; set; }
```

and

### salonlar model

```
public partial class salonlar
{
    public int salon_id { get; set; }
    public string salon_adi { get; set; }
    public string salon_adresi { get; set; }
    public string salon_aciklama { get; set; }
    public string salon_telno { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<oyunlar> oyunlars { get; set; }
}
```

### salonGetir() result

> "[{\"oyunlars\":[],\"salon_id\":300,\"salon_adi\":\"Kültür Merkezi Tiyatro Salonu\",\"salon_adresi\":\"Antakya Lisesi Karşısı\",\"salon_aciklama\":\"Kültür merkezi\",\"salon_telno\":\"03262160652\"},{\"oyunlars\":[{\"oyun_turu\":{\"oyunlars\":[{\"oyunculars\":[],\"oyun_id\":170,\"oyun_adi\":\"Kadın Bir Şiir\",\"oyun_tarihi\":\"2018-03-08T00:00:00\",\"salon_id\":400,\"tur_id\":20,\"oyun_aciklama\":\"8 Mart Dünya Kadınlar Gününde kadın daha iyi anlatılamazdı..\",\"oyun_suresi\":\"1 Saat\",\"oyun_foto\":null}],\"tur_id\":20,\"tur_adi\":\"Dram\"},\"oyunculars\":[],\"oyun_id\":160,\"oyun_adi\":\"Adı Kadın\",\"oyun_tarihi\":\"2017-09-09T00:00:00\",\"salon_id\":400,\"tur_id\":20,\"oyun_aciklama\":\"20:30 Da Meclis Kültür Sanat Merkezinde Sizlerle\",\"oyun_suresi\":\"1.5 Saat\",\"oyun_foto\":null},{\"oyun_turu\":{\"oyunlars\":[{\"oyunculars\":[],\"oyun_id\":160,\"oyun_adi\":\"Adı Kadın\",\"oyun_tarihi\":\"2017-09-09T00:00:00\",\"salon_id\":400,\"tur_id\":20,\"oyun_aciklama\":\"20:30 Da Meclis Kültür Sanat Merkezinde Sizlerle\",\"oyun_suresi\":\"1.5 Saat\",\"oyun_foto\":null}],\"tur_id\":20,\"tur_adi\":\"Dram\"},\"oyunculars\":[],\"oyun_id\":170,\"oyun_adi\":\"Kadın Bir Şiir\",\"oyun_tarihi\":\"2018-03-08T00:00:00\",\"salon_id\":400,\"tur_id\":20,\"oyun_aciklama\":\"8 Mart Dünya Kadınlar Gününde kadın daha iyi anlatılamazdı..\",\"oyun_suresi\":\"1 Saat\",\"oyun_foto\":null},{\"oyun_turu\":{\"oyunlars\":[],\"tur_id\":10,\"tur_adi\":\"Komedi\"},\"oyunculars\":[{\"oyuncu_id\":1,\"oyuncu_adi\":\"Murat\",\"oyuncu_soyadi\":\"Yılmaz\",\"oyun_id\":180,\"oyuncu_foto\":null}],\"oyun_id\":180,\"oyun_adi\":\"Eksik Bir Şey Mi Var ?\",\"oyun_tarihi\":\"2018-05-17T00:00:00\",\"salon_id\":400,\"tur_id\":10,\"oyun_aciklama\":\"O gemi bir gün gelecek !\",\"oyun_suresi\":\"2 Saat\",\"oyun_foto\":null}],\"salon_id\":400,\"salon_adi\":\"Meclis Kültür Sanat Merkezi\",\"salon_adresi\":\"General Şükrü Kanatlı Mahallesi, Cumhuriyet Alanı No:2, 31030 Antakya/Hatay\",\"salon_aciklama\":\"Meclis Kültür Sanat Merkezi\",\"salon_telno\":\"03262156000\"},{\"oyunlars\":[],\"salon_id\":500,\"salon_adi\":\"Amfi Tiyatro Sümerler\",\"salon_adresi\":\"Sümerler Mahallesi, 10. Sk. No:14, 31160 Antakya/Hatay\",\"salon_aciklama\":\"Amfi Tiyatro Sümerler\",\"salon_telno\":null}]"

***Update***

[I think it's problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyuY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid since it starts and ends with `"`.

That is not valid JSON.

*You will need to verify where that JSON is generated from, and ensure it does not put the `"` at the start and end.*